# Best way to connect VLANs / STP / LAG

Tags: vlan, spanning-tree, ieee-802.1ax

Am having a problem connecting these concepts together, like when I try thinking of them being run on the same network. I'm able to understand each of them separately, but am not able to connect them with each other .

Can someone tell me a good practice I can do to connect all these concepts together?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

VLANs are a way of partitioning a given network into distinct layer 2 segments as if you'd be using separate switches, so you don't have your whole network bunched together. The advantage of VLANs over separate switches is that you can run inter-switch connections as VLAN trunks (using tagged frames) instead of running dedicated links for each VLAN/segment, especially on long, expensive links. Additionally, the virtualization enables you to very easily provide a switch port into any segment anywhere in your network.

The spanning tree protocol takes care of removing bridge loops from your network when you've got multiple connections between switches - by accident or by choice. The original STP is very aged, today most installations use RSTP, MSTP or RPVST+, with the basic concept remaining the same. Essentially, STP blocks redundant links and avoids loops.

Link aggregation groups can aggregate multiple physical links into a single logical link to increase potential bandwidth (instead of blocking all but one link with STP).

Each of these concepts provides a solution for a networking problem and probably every seriously sized network uses them in combination.